# Download url content using Httpclient in C#

Tags: c#, url, parallel-processing

I am trying to download url content using the following method.

```
public static async Task<string> getURL(string link)
        {
            string result = "";
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(link))
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {

                result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();


            }
            return result;
        }
```

Previously I was directly loading the url through HtmlWeb.Load() method of HtmlAgilitypack. 
but it takes a lot of time, and i cannot put the code in a parallel for or foreach loop (there are a number of exceptions thrown, and the program ends after a few hundred iterations. I tried even 3 parallel threads, with no improvement). After searching on the internet, i found that writing own url download method might be a good idea. But I am not sure how can I pass one url and get url content from above method, which i copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389938/c-sharp-download-data-from-huge-list-of-urls#)
Any ideas?
Edit:
Caller method is as follows

```
public static void Download(string link)
        {
            HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
           htmlWeb.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
           HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
           document = htmlWeb.Load(getURL(link));
            if(document != null)
            {
                if(document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='urdu_results']") != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(link);
                    Console.WriteLine(count--);
                {
                    if(document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='u']") != null && document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='r']") != null)
                    {
                        var uNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='u']");
                        var rNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='r']");
                        if(uNodes.Count == rNodes.Count)
                        {
                            for(int i=0;i<uNodes.Count;i++)
                            {
                                string u = uNodes[i].InnerText.Trim();
                                string r = rNodes[i].InnerText.Trim();
                                string word = u+"\t"+r;
                                if(!words.Contains(word))
                                {
                                File.AppendAllText(output, word+Environment.NewLine);
                                Console.WriteLine(r);
                                words.Add(word);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Reuse a single shared static HttpClient in your class.  **Do not** instantiate a new HttpClient or wrap it in a using statement.  As for your other performance issues its hard to tell since you are posting a single method and not the caller.

Comment: Added caller method. it heavily uses html agility pack, but i want to improve at least url download.

Comment: You have a couple problems off the bat, you aren't using a single shared static HttpClient like I mentioned earlier.  Your `Download` method is not async, and you are not awaiting the `getUrl()` method.

Comment: Yup. I have never worked with such a method before, so no idea how to correct it. Didn't understand the code snippet in `getURL()`, probably was bad idea to copy paste in my code.

Comment: I would look into some tutorials on async/await.  A few good resources are [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await).  Basically you will need to change your Download method to: `public static async Task Download(string link)` and then put the keyword `await` in front of `getUrl()`: `document = htmlWeb.Load(await getURL(link));`

Comment: Created a shared httpclient. Removed using statements. Still there is compiler problem. `public static string getURL(string link)
        {
            string result = "";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.GetAsync(link);
            HttpContent content = response.Content;
            {

                result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();


            }
            return result;
        }`

Comment: `public static async Task<string> getURL(string link)` solved the problem. Not sure if this download method would work as nothing happens in output.

Comment: You don't have to remove all the using statements, just the one for HttpClient

Comment: i did it. there is something wrong with htmlweb.Load(). It takes a string url, i need a method to consider string output already provided.

Comment: You probably want `HtmlDocument` instead of `HtmlWeb`: `var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);`

Comment: Yes. but it does not enforce utf8, and all unicode text corrupts in httpclient download . now looking for encoding solution