# Using a Foreach loop to consume a large amount of WebServices

Tags: c#, list, loops, http, foreach

Essentially, my program needs to consume about 100 (and this number will expand) WebServices, pull a piece of data from each, store it, parse it, and then display it. I've written the code for storing, parsing, and displaying.

My problem is this: I can't find any tutorial online about how to loop through a list of WebReferences and query each one. Am I doomed to writing 100 WebReferences and manually writing queries for each one, or is it possible to store a List or Array of the URLs (or something) and loop through it? Or is there another, better way of doing this?

I've specifically done research on this and I haven't found anything, I've done my due diligence. I'm *not* asking about how to consume a WebService, there's plenty of information on that and it's not that hard.

Current foreach loop (not sufficent as I need to pass login credentials and get a response):

```
//Retrieve the XMLString from the server
//The ServerURLList is just a giant list of URLS, I didn't include it
var client = new WebClient { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("LoginCredentials", "LoginCredentialsPass") };
var XMLStringFromServer = client.DownloadString((String)(dr[0])); 
//Notice it takes the string URL from the DataTable provided, so that it can do all 100 customers while parsing the response
```

Comment: Posting code now

Comment: Do they all return the same type of data? You could store them in a config file or db then retrieve them and loop.

Comment: Yes they will all return the exact same XML spec with different values;

Comment: Should be pretty easy then to put them in some type of storage and retrieve them. If order of execution doesn't matter you could probably put them in a parallel for each to increase peformance also.

Comment: Here is a good example from another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389938/c-sharp-download-data-from-huge-list-of-urls